# Compare start of month till date to same period last month MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare total purchases from start of the month till date to the same period in the previous month and month before.

E.g 1st - 7th March, compared to 1st - 7th Feb and 1st to 7th Jan

So far, I've been able to get month till date, but I have had to manually enter the previous month dates to compare, what query do I use to get these previous dates automatically?

Current code

```
SELECT *,
current_downloads/M_1 AS `M_1_Ratio`,
current_downloads/M_2 AS `M_2_Ratio`
FROM 
(SELECT count(*) AS current_downloads
FROM `purchase`
WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')) t1
JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS M_1
FROM `purchase`
WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) BETWEEN {{date3}} AND {{date4}}) t2
JOIN 
(SELECT count(*) AS M_2
FROM `purchase`
WHERE date(`purchase`.`timestamp`) BETWEEN {{date5}} AND {{date6}}) t3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those calculations with DATE_SUB() and change the INTERVAL you want to subtract, either one or two months

e.g.

```
SELECT DATE(NOW());
+-------------+
| DATE(NOW()) |
+-------------+
| 2018-03-08  |
+-------------+

SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-02-01                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2018-02-08                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Works as planned.